# tf.multiply vs tf.matmul to calculate the dot product

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a matrix (of vectors) X with shape [3,4], and I want to calculate the dot product between each pair of vectors (X[1].X[1]) and (X[1].X[2])...etc.

I saw a cosine similarity code were they use

tf.reduce_sum(tf.multyply(X, X),axis=1)

to calculate the dot product between the vectors in a matrix of vectors.However, this result in only calculates the dot product between (X[i], X[i]).

I used tf.matmul(X, X, transpose_b=True) which calculate the dot product between every two vectors but I am still confused why tf.multiply didn't do this I think the problem with my code.

the code is:

```
data=[[1.0,2.0,4.0,5.0],[0.0,6.0,7.0,8.0],[8.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]]
X=tf.constant(data)
matResult=tf.matmul(X, X, transpose_b=True)

multiplyResult=tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(X,X),axis=1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
   print('matResult')
   print(sess.run([matResult]))
   print()
   print('multiplyResult')
   print(sess.run([multiplyResult]))
```

The output is:

```
matResult
[array([[  46.,   80.,   19.],
       [  80.,  149.,   21.],
       [  19.,   21.,   67.]], dtype=float32)]

multiplyResult
 [array([  46.,  149.,   67.], dtype=float32)]
```

I would appreciate any advise

Comment: `tf.multiply` gives you the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`tf.multiply(X, Y)` or the `*` operator does **element-wise multiplication** so that:

```
[[1 2]    [[1 3]      [[1 6]
 [3 4]] .  [2 1]]  =   [6 4]]
```

wheras `tf.matmul` does **matrix multiplication** so that:

```
[[1 0]    [[1 3]      [[1 3]
 [0 1]] .  [2 1]]  =   [2 1]]
```

using `tf.matmul(X, X, transpose_b=True)` means that you are calculating `X . X^T` where `^T` indicates the transposing of the matrix and `.` is the matrix multiplication.

`tf.reduce_sum(_, axis=1)` takes the sum along 1st axis (starting counting with 0) which means you are suming the rows:

```
tf.reduce_sum([[a, b], [c, d]], axis=1) = [a+b, c+d]
```

This means that:

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(X, X), axis=1) = [X[1].X[1], ..., X[n].X[n]]
```

so that is the one you want if you only want the norms of each rows. On the other hand:

```
tf.matmul(X, X, transpose_b=True) = [
                                      [ X[1].X[1], X[1].X[2], ..., X[1].X[n] ], 
                                      [ X[2].X[1], ..., X[2].X[n] ],
                                       ...
                                      [ X[n].X[1], ..., X[n].X[n] ]
                                   ]
```

so that is what you need if you want the similarity between all pairs of rows.

Comment: As a side note, `tf.multiply(a,b)` is identical to `a*b`

Answer (score 5):

What `tf.multiply(X, X)` does is essentially multiplying each element of the matrix with itself, like

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

would turn into

```
[[1 4]
 [9 16]]
```

whereas `tf.reduce_sum(_, axis=1)` takes a sum of each row, so the result for the previous example will be

```
[5 25]
```

which is exactly (by definition) equal to `[X[0, :] @ X[0, :], X[1, :] @ X[1, :]]`.

Just put it down with variable names `[[a b] [c d]]` instead of actual numbers and look at what does `tf.matmul(X, X)` and `tf.multiply(X, X)` do.

Answer (score 4):

In short **tf.multiply()** does element wise product(dot product).
whereas **tf.matmul()** does actual matrix mutliplication.
so **tf.multiply()** needs arguments of same shape so that element wise product is possible i.e.,shapes are **(n,m) and (n,m)**. But **tf.matmul()** needs arguments of shape **(n,m) and (m,p)** so that resulting matrix is (n,p) [ usual math ].

Once understood, this can be applied to Multi-Dimensional matrices easily.

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, `XdotX = tf.matmul(X, X, transpose_b=True)` is functionally equivalent to

```
X_left = tf.expand_dims(X, axis=-2)
X_right = tf.expand_dims(X, axis=-3)
XdotX = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(X_left, X_right), axis=-1, keepdims=False)
```

If `X` is `(M,N)` dimensional:

- `X_left` will be `(M,1,N)` dimensional.
  `X_left[i][0][k]` will equal `X[i][k]`.
- `X_right` will be `(1,M,N)` dimensional.
  `X_right[0][j][k]` will equal `X[j][k]`.
- `tf.multiply(X_left, X_right)` will be `(M,M,N)` dimensional.
  `tf.multiply(X_left, X_right)[i][j][k]` will equal `X[i][k]*X[j][k]`.

Summing over the `k` index with `tf.reduce_sum` with `axis=-1` will produce the desired result.

---

Dot product between different matrices `X` and `Y` `tf.matmul(X, Y, transpose_b=True)` can be accomplished the same way, by using using `tf.expand_dims` with `axis=-3` on `Y` instead of X.

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment! I was wondering what operation adds the 'ExpandDims' nodes in my TensorFlow frozen graphs even though I never used tf.expand_dims explicitly in my model definition. This comment literally saved my time!